# ggpairs Change the colum label of factor levels

Tags: r, ggplot2

It is possible to change the column label of factor levels without having to change the values in the data.frame

for example in the following graph can I change the label of Female and Male to F and M respectively without having to change the df?

```
library(GGally)
data(tips, package = "reshape")
pm <- ggpairs(tips, 1:3, columnLabels = c("Total Bill", "Tip", "Sex"))
pm
```

[image: tips]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After

```
pm <- ggpairs(tips, 1:3, columnLabels = c("Total Bill", "Tip", "Sex"))
```

do this

```
levels(pm$data$sex)[levels(pm$data$sex) == "Male"] = "M"
levels(pm$data$sex)[levels(pm$data$sex) == "Female"] = "F"
```

You'll get this plot:

[image]

It won't change anything in `tips` dataset:

```
head(tips)

 total_bill  tip    sex smoker day   time size
1     16.99 1.01 Female     No Sun Dinner    2
2     10.34 1.66   Male     No Sun Dinner    3
3     21.01 3.50   Male     No Sun Dinner    3
4     23.68 3.31   Male     No Sun Dinner    2
5     24.59 3.61 Female     No Sun Dinner    4
6     25.29 4.71   Male     No Sun Dinner    4
```